# Laravel 5.2 - Enable Cors - Nothing Works

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I cannot get my Angular App working with an $http.post request. No matter what I do, I always get as a result:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.com/public/apiendpoint.
>   Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

I had tried with [Barryvdh Cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors), making my own middleware, even putting headers inside controller

**Cors Middleware**

```
class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
       return $next($request)
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
     }
}
```

**Headers inside Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request){
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
      header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type' );

      $input = $request->all();
      MyModel::create($input);
      return response()->JSON(["save"=>"ok"]);
}
```

How can I enable CORS please???

P.D. - Works fine with Postman, but nothing works in angularjs post.

Angular code: **EDITED**

```
  $scope.soloPlay = function(){
    //Enviamos la cancion y nada más
    var dataObj = {
      uri: $scope.selTrack.uri,
      user: $scope.selTrack.user,
      quote: ""
};
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://jukebox.adagal.com/public/cancion',
      data: dataObj
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log("POST OK: "+JSON.stringify(response));
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log("POST FAIL: "+JSON.stringify(response));
    });

  }
```

Comment: try after removing header from from angular post

Comment: I did. It is not the problem. The server is accepting CORS from *, I have checked, but cannot POST from angular. Se my new code on the post

Comment: You're not setting the right headers in the middlewhere. Is the controller even being hit by a request (it might not be since it is the preflight OPTIONS request that is failing)